# Bash: Increment a counter variable within a string

Tags: bash, shell

In Bash, I'm trying to increment a counter variable (number) from within a text string. If I call the counter var alone it increments successfully, but If I echo the string variable on each iteration of my loop, the counter variable does not increment.

```
#!/bin/bash

number=1

yes="number$number/"

for i in 1 2 3
do
    echo $number

    echo $yes

    ((number++))

done
```

I get this output:

```
1
number1/
2
number1/
3
number1/
```

Whereas I expect this:

```
1
number1/
2
number2/
3
number3/
```

I have also tried this:

```
yes="number${number}/"
```

..which gave the same incorrect result.

Thanks

Comment: `yes="number$number/"` is assigned once. It does not update when the value of `$number` changes.

Comment: Do you know how I would get the $number variable in the string to update when $number changes?

Comment: @Jon: You cannot. Expansion happens only at the time of assignment. You'll have to move the assignment to the place where you have the right value in `$number` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
    echo $number
    yes="number$number/"
    echo $yes

    ((number++))

done
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've been told in comments, expansion happens at the time of assignment. The variable `$yes` contains a string which includes the value of `$number` at the time of assignment. After assignment, there is nothing in the content of `$yes` which would indicate any connection to the variable `$number`.

There are two common ways to get this kind of functionality.

First, you can use `eval`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

number=1

yes='number$number/'    # note the single quotes

for i in 1 2 3; do

    echo "$number"
    eval "echo \"$yes\""
    ((number++))

done
```

Note that the value of `$yes` is NOT being updated here -- it's simply being used to expand what is printed by `echo`.

You will find that many people discourage the use of `eval`, as it can have unintended security related consequences.

Second, you could just update `yes` each time you run through the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

number=1

for i in 1 2 3; do

    echo "$number"

    yes="number$number/"
    echo "$yes"

    ((number++))

done
```

If you're looking to use this for formatting, then `printf` is your friend:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

number=1

yesfmt='number%d\n'

for i in 1 2 3; do

    echo "$number"
    printf "$yesfmt" "$number"
    ((number++))

done
```

Without knowing the bigger picture or what you're trying to achieve, it's difficult to recommend a strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Use a function (I changed the name from `yes` to `report` because `yes` is a standard posix utility, and anyway it wasn't at all descriptive.)

```
#!/bin/bash
number=1
report() { echo "number$number/"; }
for i in 1 2 3; do
  echo $number
  report
  ((number++))
done
```